# GET <URL> net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-web-api

I have WebAPI controller which returns JSON. Code looks like this:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using GetWork.Data;
using GetWork.Models.Domain;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Cors;

namespace GetWork.Controllers.Api
{
    [Produces("application/json")]
    [EnableCors("SiteCorsPolicy")]
    public class ConversationsApiController : Controller
    {
        private readonly ApplicationDbContext _context;

        public ConversationsApiController(ApplicationDbContext context)
        {
            _context = context;
        }
        //This one works fine
        // GET: api/Conversations/5
        [HttpGet]
        [Route("api/conversations/getconversations/{id}")]
        public List<Conversation> GetConversations(int id)
        {
            var conversations = _context.Conversations.Include(o => o.Offerer).Where(c => c.JobRelated.ID == id).ToList();

            return conversations ?? new List<Conversation>();
        }
        //This one works fine
        [HttpGet]
        [Route("api/conversations/getmyoffers/{userId}")]
        public List<Job> GetMyOffers(string userId)
        {
            return _context.Job.Include(c => c.Conversations).ToList();

        }

    }
}
```

When calling GetMyOffers method, in browser i can see such error:

```
GET http://localhost:8377/api/conversations/getMyOffers/70a741c2-b847-4063-ab94-7f2e93860ab6 net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET
```

But when I hardcode data (omiting _context), everything works fine. Other methods are working.

What can cause such issue?

**UPDATE:**

Finally I've found such expection:

```
Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException: Self referencing loop detected for property 'job' with type 'GetWork.Models.Domain.Job'
```

Need to verify my model.

**SOLUTION:**

Self referencing loop could not be handled by serializer by default. I've put following line to configuration:

```
options.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore;
```

It ignores all circular references during serialization. It worked for me, but I'm aware it's work around rather than a fix. (Considering using DTO's instead of pure model).

Comment: Can you update your code to be clearer about which URL **is** working and which one **isn't**?

Comment: Did you try debugging that? Check when exactly does it fail. If you have MSSQL underneath you can try profiling to view if problem appears before the actual query to the database or after. Other option is to go to Exception Settings while debugging and marking CLR Exceptions checked to catch more exceptions in debug mode.

Comment: Profiling for some reason does not work, but finally I've found the root of a problem, I believe. (Check update)

Answer (score 0):

If it works when you remove the _context and just returns hardcoded data, i would suspect that it most likely is a timeout:

May be fixed by increasing the request timeout e.g. :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
   <system.webServer>
             ....
        <aspNetCore requestTimeout="00:20:00"  .... />
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

You could increase the robustness of your code by wrapping  `_context.Job.Include(c => c.Conversations).ToList();`
in a try catch block and return something meaningful when an exception is thrown e.g.

```
try {
   return _context.Job.Include(c => c.Conversations).ToList();
}
catch(Exception ex) {
   return something meaningful here...
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. The XML code you've provided belongs to web.config file I believe. I'm not sure, if I can use it since I'm using MVC 6 and whole configuration sits in appsettings.json.

Comment: You are correct, the above configuration only applies if you are hosting your app in IIS, sorry the answer  wasn't helpful

Comment: Can I somehow change default server to IIS? As far as I know, MVC 6 uses by default Kestrel server and uses IIS only as a reverse-proxy.